# Calculating CPU time of process in RHEL 5.3

Tags: linux, rhel, time, ps, process-management

For a process management,I would need to remove a process that exceeds a certain amount of CPU time, for example 1 hour.In PS command ,it has TIME parameter shows the total CPU time of a process .So is this the correct way to take the CPU time of a process?
Also is there any other commands that could be used in calculating CPU time of process.

Comment: you probably need to use  `ps` or `top` with the right option added to `cut` and then to `kill -9`   but I think nobody will provide you such a script without you showing a bit of your work.

Comment: If you already know what process is exceeding, you could use `sar -X` to monitor that specific PID.

Answer (score 4):

On most systems, you can use the [`ulimit`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-ulimit) command when you start the program to limit the amount of CPU time it can use. Under the hood, this calls [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with the argument `RLIMIT_CPU`. After the program has used that much time, the program is killed.

```
(ulimit -t 3600; myprogram)
```

You can refine further by setting a soft limit after which the program receives the `SIGXCPU` signal (which it can catch) and a hard limit after which the program receives the `SIGKILL` signal (which is unavoidably fatal).

```
(ulimit -t -S 3590; ulimit -t -H 3600; myprogram)
```

I don't know of any shell utility to change the limit of a running program. You can cause the process to execute the `setrlimit` system call via [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace), for example using a debugger. Note that some security frameworks disable this use of `ptrace` (e.g. it's disabled by default on current Ubuntu releases), I don't know whether RHEL 5 allows it.

```
gdb -n -pid 1234 -batch -x /dev/stdin <<EOF
call setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, {(rlim_t) 3590, (rlim_t) 3600})
detach
quit
EOF
```

(`1234` is the process ID, and the two numbers inside the braces are the soft and hard limit.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the precision you need, invoking `ps` and some friends may be sufficient.

However, keep in mind that ps gets its data from somewhere; there's nothing magical about that particular application.

Have a look at `/proc/$$/sched` and specifically the value for `se.sum_exec_runtime`. That value is [the total number of nanoseconds the process has spent on the CPU](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Ebaker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/sched.h#L473). I'm not going to spend a lot of time to trace its history, but it looks like [the value has been kept track of at least since 2.6.32](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/fs/proc/base.c#L386).

To get a more useful value (milliseconds), take the reported value and divide it by 1,000,000.

There are probably other ways to get the same data, but it might be non-trivial without resorting to syscalls into the kernel, which is not an easy thing to do from a shell script.